# Friends Problem (Basic Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

Let $k$ and $n$ be fixed integers. In a group of $k$ people, any group of $n$ people all have a friend in common.

1. If $k=2 n + 1$ prove that there exists a person who is friends with everyone else.
2. If $k=2n+2$, give an example of a group of $k$ people satisfying the given condition, but with no person being friends with everyone else.

Thanks :)

Comment: Again... what did you try?

Comment: I tired working out the number of groups of n people amongst 2n+1 people but I can't get it

Comment: You mean you do not know the number of ways of **choosing** n people amongst 2n+1? (And why did you try to work this out?)

Comment: Umm... I thought it would be a good start but... Argh! Any idea how to solve this question? It's for a maths assignment due in a few days and if I don't do it my teacher will be real BLEAK

Answer (score 3):

For the second part, divide the $k$ people into $k/2=n+1$ pairs and let the two people in each pair not be friends, while everybody is a friend with all those people they are not paired with. As any group of $n$ people involve at most $n$ of these pairs, the remaining pair are friends with everybody in the group. (Lesson: Taking complements, i.e., working with the graph of non-friends, can be useful sometimes.)

Thinking about how this example just barely works might give you some ideas for proving the first part.

Comment: I'm horribly sorry, I do not understand what you are saying :| Can you please explain it as you would to a complete and utter imbecile retard? I am only 15 and have barely any experience with this kind of maths...

Comment: Sorry, that might require a drawing, and I have no further time to spend here today. Maybe someone else will step up to the plate.

Comment: Ugh,... anyway thanks Harald Hanche-Olsen, I appreciate your answer :D I might be able to work stuff out from that

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with a small example for problem 2, $n=2, k=6$.  Number the people $1$ through $6$.  As Harald Hanche-Olsen says, let $1$ not be friends with $2$, $3$ not friends $4$, and $5$ not friends with $6$.  Because of the symmetry, there are only two kinds of sets of $n$ to see if they have a mutual friend:  $1$ and $2$, who have $3,4,5,6$ as mutual friends, and $1$ and $3$, who have $5$ and $6$ as mutual friends.

The general idea is that any set of $n$ people only have $n$ non-friends among them, leaving $2$ people who are friends with all of them.

For problem 1, the key insight is that at least one person has two non-friends.  Again take $n=2, k=5$.  $1$ is not friends with $2$, $3$ not friends with $4$, but $5$ has to be non-friends with somebody, say $1$.  Now the $n=2$ people $1,3$ don't have any friends in common.  You will have to work on generalizing this.  The idea is that if you take a group of $n$ people, you have $n+1$ non-friends if one of the $n$ is the person with two non-friends.  That is everybody ($n+(n+1)=k$) so the group has no mutual friend.

Comment: Hmm... I sort of see what you're saying... Thanks for your contribution! :)

Comment: @mathsnoob:  I added a sentence.  See if that helps.

Comment: Yea, sorta... So you're saying that question 2 is impossible?

Comment: @mathsnoob:  no, question 2 is quite possible.  I gave a specific solution for $n=2, k=6$ and Harald Hanche-Olsen the general one.  For question 1 we were asked to prove that it was impossible unless somebody was friends with everyone and that is correct.

Comment: I apologize for my lack of any mathematical knowledge or understanding whatsoever. Thanks to your contributions, I think I'm beginning to understand a little. Sigh...

Answer (score 1):

The first part of this is just an expansion of Harald Hanche-Olsen’s answer.

For the second part number the $2n+2$ people $P_1,\dots,P_{n+1},Q_1,\dots,Q_{n+1}$. Divide them into pairs: $\{P_1,Q_1\},\{P_2,Q_2\},\dots,\{P_{n+1},Q_{n+1}\}$. The two people in each pair are **not** friends; i.e., $P_k$ is **not** friends with $Q_k$ for $k=1,\dots,n+1$. However, every other possible pair of people in the group are friends. In particular,

- $P_k$ is friends with $P_i$ whenever $1\le i,k\le n+1$ and $i\ne k$,
- $Q_k$ is friends with $Q_i$ whenever $1\le i,k\le n+1$ and $i\ne k$, and
- $P_k$ is friends with $Q_i$ whenever $1\le i,k\le n+1$ and $i\ne k$.

In short, two people in the group are friends if and only if they have different subscripts. Clearly no person in the group is friends with everyone else in the group. Suppose, though, that $\mathscr{A}$ is a group of $n$ of these people. The people in $\mathscr{A}$ have altogether at most $n$ different subscripts, so there is at least one subscript that isn’t used by anyone in $\mathscr{A}$; let $k$ be such a subscript. Then everyone in $\mathscr{A}$ has a different subscript from $P_k$ and is therefore friends with $P_k$ (and for that matter with $Q_k$).

I hope to get to the first part a bit later.

Comment: Oh... I finally get what the others (and you) were trying to explain to me!!! I'm such an idiot, how did I not understand?!

Comment: @mathsnoob: I’m glad that it helped. I shouldn’t feel too bad about being a little slow to see it: this is not a particularly easy problem. And I find that especially with combinatorics problems it’s often the case that the wording of a solution has a very large effect on how easily I can follow it.

Comment: So... Do you think maybe you could solve question 1 as well? Is it an easier problem or a harder one?

Comment: @mathsnoob: Unless I’m simply not seeing something, it’s harder. In particular, I don’t think that Ross’s idea works without a lot more argument. I’m still thinking about it.

Comment: Thank you oh kind sir from heaven ;)

Comment: Sir Brian... please can you solve the first part as well? It's for a homework assignment due tomorrow but I just can't get the first part...

Comment: @mathsnoob: I’ve given it some thought, but so far a solution has eluded me. I can prove that everyone has at least $n$ friends, and I can prove that if there **isn’t** someone who is friends with everyone else, then there is someone who has at least two non-friends, but neither of those observations leads to a proof in any straightforward way that I’ve yet seen. I may, as the Germans say, just have a board in front of my face and be missing something simple $-$ that can easily happen with combinatorial problems. I need to take a break from it and come back to it, but I will post if I get it.

Comment: Thanks for trying, Brian M. Scott. Take your time - it just needs to be in tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Sir Brian, will this answer work? In the second part (where you explained everything beautifully) you said for group 'weird A' to all have a friend in common, it would have to be $Pk$ that they are friends with, and because $Pk$ only has 1 non-friend, if we were to subtract one person from the group $k$, then $Pk$ wouldn't have a non-friend anymore and hence is friends with everyone else?

Comment: @mathsnoob: The problem with that idea is that in part (2) were just finding one example, so we could set up whatever friendships we needed to make it work. In part (1) we have to come up with an argument that works for **all** sets of friendships satisfying the conditions of the problem. It may not always be possible, for instance, to find $n$ pairs of non-friends.

Comment: Ugh... Just out of interest, when do you think you will be able to solve part (1) fully? I'm terribly sorry to keep bugging you like this... But this kind of Olympiad questions should be no major mission for you right? Do you think you will be able to solve it by... say... 4 hours? I know this is a lot to ask, but it's for an assignment... I'm really stressing... Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: @mathsnoob: To be honest, I can’t guarantee that I will solve it. It requires coming up with the right insight, and I may simply not manage it, at least in any reasonable amount of time. This is a non-trivial problem, definitely contest-worthy. (And I’m going to have to get some sleep fairly soon now!) I’d love to solve it $-$ it’s thoroughly engaged my interest $-$ and I’ve not given up, but I make no promises.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Non-trivial huh! My grade school teacher is giving out these kind of maths problems to 14 year olds like me :D I appreciate your dedication, and if you can't solve it, it's not a big deal. But it would be nice if you could... If you can't solve it today, then could you try tomorrow as well please? I need to hand it in at about 1:00pm GMT.

Comment: Hi Brian M. Scott, have you got anywhere with the problem yet? Sorry to keep asking you, but I need it in about... 5 hours. Please don't get the idea that you NEED to solve it for me, I really don't mind that much if you can't solve it, but it would be really great if you could... Thanks!